# How to NOT wrap stored procedure within another stored procedure for EF?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure in my database that I'm calling through EF. This is the line of code that I'm using to call it:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(u => u.Delete(t => t.HasName("UserDelete")
                                         .Parameter(b => b.ID, "@UserId")));
```

I see EF wrapping this into a stored procedure of its own, so it's turning out to be a stored procedure running within another stored procedure that was created by EF. Is there a way to make EF NOT create a stored procedure for hitting the one that's in the database?

Answer (score 0):

EF uses the recommended way of executing your stored procedure. Most probably, you don't need to alter this behavior. Please see [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/) for more information.